# Magento 2 : Custom phtml file add in product page

Tags: magento2, layout, catalog

How to add custom .phtml file in product details page.
I also try this code in catalog_product_view.xml file, but can't working.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block after="product.info.details" class="Vendor/Module/Block/Module" name="extra" template="Vendor_Module::extra.phtml" />        
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Can I add this custom.phtml file in product page on installation of a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code, Your phtml file content will display near social icon, You can change referenceBlock name if you want to change position

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.social">
            <block class="Example\Examples\Block\Question" name="example.tab" template="Example_Examples::success.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```