# Not able to add Custom phtml file on Product Page - Magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2, magento2.2.4

I can't able to add/include my custom phtml file on product detailed page.

Here is my entire flow :

1. Added the following code in **app/design/frontend/Themename/themedirectory/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml file**

   ```
   <body>
           <referenceContainer name="content">
               <container name="product-main-content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-main-content" before="-">
                   </container>
                  </referenceContainer>

           <referenceContainer name="content.top.most">
               <container name="custom.block.sec" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-class" before="-">
               <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="my_custom" template="Vendorname_Modulename::custom.phtml" />
               </container>
           </referenceContainer>

             <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" name="page.main.sub.title" template="Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml"/>

               <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
             <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="cmsinfo.tab" as="cmsinfo" template="product/view/cms_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
               <arguments>
                 <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
               </arguments>
              </block>
            </referenceBlock>

             <move element="custom.block.sec" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>

   </body>
   ```
2. Added the custom.phtml file in **app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/custom.phtml**
3. custom.phtml file content

   Custom File Works

I referred this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128692/magento-2-custom-phtml-file-add-in-product-page)  as well but no luck.

But its not working. Why?

Can anyone let me know what's the issue & how to add the custom file in product page?

Comment: I've edited for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way in your `app/design/frontend/Themename/themedirectory/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` file

```
<referenceContainer name="content.top.most">
    <container name="custom.block.sec" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-class" before="-">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="my_custom" template="Vendorname_Modulename::custom.phtml" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>

<move element="custom.block.sec" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
```

After that please check with clear your cache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just tried the code but its not working. I have updated my entire code in question. Please check it

Comment: did you clear cache after this changes ?

Comment: Yes cleared cache by **php bin/magento cache:flush** and **php bin/magento cache:clean** But its not working

Comment: its strange, because its working fine for me. can you please check your custom module name is Vendorname_Modulename which is correct ?

Comment: @Mesk clear your cache and refresh cache from admin and once check.

Comment: @AasimGoriya I just checked & confirmed Vendorname_Modulename is correct

Comment: @Rizwan I have cleared the cache but still its not working

Comment: @Mesk please add some sample text in custom.phtml file and check after that.

Comment: Also please try to copy your custom.phtml file from your module directory and paste into this directory app/design/frontend/Themename/themedirectory/Vendorname_Modulename/templates/custom.phtml

Comment: @AasimGoriya I just copied custom.phtml file from module directory to app/design/frontend/Themename/themedirectory/Vendorname_Modulename/templates/custom.phtml  but still its not showing.

Comment: Do we need to modify anything other than above?

Comment: No, you don't need to add anything else, I have used this lots of times and its working very fine for me, you have something else in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88667/discussion-between-mesk-and-aasim-goriya).

Comment: @Mesk please accept my ans and upvote if its useful to you :)

Comment: @AasimGoriya I accepted & upvote it